# Not able to deploy flutter app on firebase. Deployed app showing blank screen

Tags: flutter, firebase, deployment

I have used Firebase authentication , storage and   Firestore  database for this app,

I am deploying it in Firebase, but after deploying app only blank screen is visible
When I click on inspect it is showing this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading ' gqr ')
    at main.dart.js:44113:27
    at apN.a (main.dart.js:5574:62)
    at apN.$2 (main.dart.js:36469:14)




Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received
```

I have tried removing base href="" but it didn't worked please help me out